# Finding the function by an infinite sum

Tags: infinite-product, weierstrass-factorization

I have found an infinite sum $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{(n+1)^2x^2}{n^4}\Big)$$ This function acts similarly to the sine function, as shown in the diagram below:
[image]
This function diverges when the value $n\rightarrow \infty$.
So the question is: what is the function that could represent this infinite product?

---

This function has its zeros when $x=\pm \frac{k^2}{k+1}$ where $k$ is any positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1+-+%28%281+%2B+n%29%5E2*x%5E2%29%2Fn%5E4%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D), we do not get much except the interesting last expression using Pochammer symbols
$$P_m=\prod_{n=1}^{m}\Bigg(1-\frac{(n+1)^2x^2}{n^4}\Bigg)$$
$$(m!)^4 P_m=\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\sqrt{x-4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)_m \times\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(x+\sqrt{x-4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)_m \times$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-x-\sqrt{x-4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)_m \times\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(-x+\sqrt{x-4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)_m $$

Now, using asymptotics
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigg(1-\frac{(n+1)^2x^2}{n^4}\Bigg)$$ is the reciprocal of the product of four gamma functions
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\sqrt{x-4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)\times 
\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(x+\sqrt{x-4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)\times $$
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-x-\sqrt{x+4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)\times 
\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-x+\sqrt{x+4} \sqrt{x}+2\right)\right)$$